# The UITextfield does not provide user created Keyboard Shortcut / Text Replacement options

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

In the app, when attempting to log in, the keyboard does not provide the text replacement/short cuts for email that a user may have set up in the phone settings.  How does one programmatically turn off or disable what is blocking it from providing the email as an option when entering the text shortcut?

Comment: can u be more specifc ? You can access the text shortcuts anywhere in your device.

Comment: Yes. For example, if `gml` is the shortcut for my gmail address, I can write that anywhere else on the device and my whole gmail address will show up as a replacement option either in the autocorrect bar or as a bubble by the text field.  This does not happen though in my app.

Comment: strange that never happened to me. Did u set autocorrectionType to No ?

Comment: It's set to `UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes` but trying `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo` or `UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault` do not solve the problem.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No I did not @marchiore - no longer on that project so don't have access to the code base to check if things have changed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case delegate method

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

should return YES